# How to choose a random question from items in a list/dict imported from a CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to code a quiz as a homework assignment. The very last step involves me randomizing the order in which the questions are asked.

I'm not sure how to do this, because I'm not 100% sure even how my existing code works - whether to pick it from the CSV file itself or from the list/dict (is it a list or a dictionary?).

```
score=0
questionno=0
def parse_csv(file_name: str) -> dict:
    retval = {}
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.strip().split(',')
            key, *values = (v.strip() for v in data)
            retval[key] = values
    return retval

questions = parse_csv('questions.txt')
for question, answers in questions.items():
    questionno+=1
    correct = answers[-1]
    answers = answers[:-1]
    print(questionno)
    result = input(f"{question}: {','.join(answers)}")
    if result=="A" or result=="B" or result=="C" or result=="D":
        if result == correct:
            print('Correct!')
            score+=1
        else:
            print(f'The correct answer is {correct!r}')
            break
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        break

print(score)
```

Comment: If you coded it how are you unsure how it works? Also for us to have a better grasp on what the data is you're reading, please provide the contents or a sample thereof for `'questions.txt'`

Comment: @Jab No, I didn't code the bulk of this. The extension task was to expand on the existing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, dictionaries in Python don't have any order (see [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) for that), but when you iterate over it the order isn't really random either!

Here's what I suggest to make the question order truly random:

```py
from random import shuffle


questions = parse_csv('questions.txt')
shuffledquestions = list(questions.items())
shuffle(shuffledquestions)
for (question, answer) in shuffledquestions:
    questionno+=1
    correct = answers[-1]
    answers = answers[:-1]
    print(questionno)
    result = input(f"{question}: {','.join(answers)}")
    if result=="A" or result=="B" or result=="C" or result=="D":
        if result == correct:
            print('Correct!')
            score+=1
        else:
            print(f'The correct answer is {correct!r}')
            break
    else:
        print("Invalid Entry")
        break
```

The idea is making a list of (question, answer) Tuple, shuffle it using [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) and then iterate over it.

*EDIT: I forgot that shuffle() was in place and didn't return the list, now it should work*

Comment: Thank you! Question, though: I thought it was a dictionary? Then why the shuffle(list( etc?

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer, you can't directly shuffle a dictionnary, so we make a list of the questions and shuffle this list instead

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It says that "NoneType" object is not iterable, with regards to the line for question in shuffledquestions:

Comment: whoops my bad, shuffle doesn't return a new list, so I edited my code again, can you check now ?

Comment: It returns with this error message: File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 275, in shuffle
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
>>>

Comment: well it seems a NoneType object was passed to shuffle() function, this is not related to my code, I've tested it and it works

Comment: Oh no sorry, it was just a typo haha! It works, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

It is a dictionary. You could use [numpy.random.shuffle](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) after converting dictionary to list of tuples like so:

```
import numpy as np

questions = list(parse_csv('questions.txt').items())
np.random.shuffle(questions)
for question, answers in questions:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the question again if the user enters invalid entry - Also it shuffles the order.

```
import random
score=0
questionno=0
def parse_csv(file_name: str) -> dict:
    retval = {}
    with open(file_name) as f:
        for line in f:
            data = line.strip().split(',')
            key, *values = (v.strip() for v in data)
            retval[key] = values
    return retval
questions = parse_csv('questions.txt')
l = list(questions.items())
random.shuffle(l)
questions = dict(l)
for question, answers in questions.items():
    questionno+=1
    correct = answers[-1]
    answers = answers[:-1]
    while True:    
        result = input(f"{question}: {','.join(answers)}")
        if result=="A" or result=="B" or result=="C" or result=="D":
            if result == correct:
                print('Correct!')
                score+=1
                break
            else:
                print(f'The correct answer is {correct!r}')
                break
        else:
            print("Invalid Entry\n Try again...")
```